# Check for empty column and set value to it in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have model, which is look like this

```
class Question(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'questions'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    question_title = db.Column(db.String(64))
    question_text = db.Column(db.String(256), nullable=False)
    votest = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0)
    answers = db.relationship('Answer', backref='question')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<QTitle: %s>\n<QText: %s>' % (self.question_title,
                                          self.question_text)
```

The thing is to check if column `question_title` is empty, and assign it to first 64 symbols of column `question_text` + '...'.
Which is the best way to implement this?

Maybe the best way is not to implement this in **`model`**, but make this check in **`view`**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to do this in your view after you read the data from a form (if this is the case).

You could create a helper function which takes as arguments `question_title` and `question_text` and verifies if the `question_title` is empty and if it is then assign to it the first 64 characters from `question_text`. And you call this function in your view after you get the data from the form (or from wherever you get the data). And after that you put the data in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
# Query all Question objects with empty question_title  
empties = session.query(Question).filter_by(question_title=None).all()

# Iterate over them
for empty_q in empties:

    # Apply the logic
    empty_q.question_title = empty_q.question_text[:64] + '...'
    session.add(empty_q)

session.commit()

print "Updated Empty Questions!"
```

I didn't test it, but it should work!